# Not able to add ipv6 type Load Balancer IP in kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, service, google-kubernetes-engine, ipv6

I'm on GKE and I'm trying to expose one application using IPV6 address.

This is my service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
  labels:
    run: ubuntu
  name: ubuntu
  namespace: default
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: "<ipv6-address>"
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv6
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30783
    port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5001
  selector:
    run: ubuntu
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

This is my gcloud address list

```
deletable-pzk-reg-ip2-6           <ipv6-address>/96  EXTERNAL                    us-central1  pzksubnet1  RESERVED
```

I'm getting this error

```
  Warning  SyncLoadBalancerFailed  13s (x6 over 2m49s)  service-controller  Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: requested ip "<ipv6-address>" is neither static nor assigned to the LB
```

Please help me in debugging this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below troubleshooting steps can help you to resolve your issue:

1. IPv6 is only for HTTP, SSL Proxy and TCP proxy and make sure you are using one of them.
2. The following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#use_an_ingress) describes creation of an Ingress resource.

- Using the following reserve a regional external IPv6 address.

  `- gcloud compute addresses create <your-ipv6-address-name> --global --ip-version=IPv6`
- Specify the global ip address in the YAML file using the annotation:

  `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: <your-ipv6-address-name>`

3. If you want to use load balancer check the [Load balancer parameters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service-load-balancer-parameters#service_parameters), example: After [reserving the static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#external-ip) use it as loadBalancedIP in yaml, the load balancer will be created.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Servicemetadata:
  name: my-lb-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: <ip>
```

Attaching a blog [HTTP on Load Balancer and IPv6](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-cloud-http-load-balancer-and-ipv6/) authored by John Hanley for your reference.

Comment: Thank you. 
Using part of one other link - https://www.willianantunes.com/blog/2021/05/gke-ingress-how-to-configure-ipv4-and-ipv6-addresses/
and some links given here, I was able to find an acceptable solution.